# Set Multiple Marker Google Map From Data Object

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

Hy everyone,

I have code like this

```
var locations = [
    [-33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    [-33.923036, 151.259052, 5]
];

var res = {
    destination: {lat: -6.3207993, lng: 106.7261287},
    departure: {lat: -6.170885, lng: 106.813184}
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
    });
}
```

And Iwant to display data object **res** to be marker on google maps, how to display **res** data object to array for create marker? can anybody help me please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over `res`'s values to create new markers

```
Object.values(res).forEach(({ lat, lng }) => {
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map
  });
});
```